# Unable to create recovery vault using ARM

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault, azure-site-recovery

I am getting the following error while creating a recovery vault using ARM.

```
{"status":"Failed",
"error":
{"code":"DeploymentFailed",
"message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
"details":
[{"code":"BadRequest",
"message":"{\r\n \"error\": 
{\r\n \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n \"message\": \"An invalid parameter MigrationSolutionId and VMwareToAzureProviderType was passed.\",\r\n \"detaiecovery vault. 
At least one server needs to be registered to perform this operation.\",
\r\n \"possibleCauses\": \"The operation failed due to an internal error.\",\r\n \"recommendedAction\": \"Fix the issue and Retry the last action. 
If the issue persists, contact Support.\",\r\n \"clientRequestId\": \"83e60574-b6e1-4834-aa45-b0d237b05c1e\",\r\n \"activityId\": \"530f1c71-fa5a-4f4d-b7b2-639896eeadf4\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}}
```

Initially, I created a recovery vault using the Azure portal. Then I changed some properties in the"`back up policies" tab. I downloaded the ARM template format from the portal and tried to create a recovery vault in a different Resource group using that ARM. I got the above issue, and I am not getting much help from the internet. Please help

Answer (score 0):

- Check whether you have `Microsoft. recovery services vaults` are created in your template. and here is the Sample template that creates Vaults using ARM.

[image]

- And here is the [sample template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/quickstart-create-vault-template?tabs=CLI#review-the-template) for creating a vault and configuring the vault's backup redundancy settings.
  After deploying the template to validate the deployment and check whether the vault is created, here is the CLI command to check.

```html
 echo "Enter the resource group name:" &&
    read resourceGroupName &&
    echo "Enter the vault name:" &&
    read vaultName &&
    az backup vault show --name $vaultName --resource-group $resourceGroupName &&
    az backup vault backup-properties show --name $vaultName --resource-group $resourceGroupName &&
    echo "Press [ENTER] to continue ..."
```

- Here is the output with newly created vault's information.

[image]